# How can I round numbers (2 decimal) parseXml get(field) in Android

Tags: android, decimal, rounding, parsexml

> TextView.setText(XMLdata.get("XMLField") + " mm");

input values that are expressed in an abbreviated way:

`10,5858555966668` (with comma)

Which I would like to convert into:

```
10,58
```

Comment: Something like `yourNumber.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `XMLdata.get("XMLField")` value is `float` u can do the following code

```
String finalValue = String.format(
                    "%.2f", XMLdata.get("XMLField"));

TextView.setText(finalValue + " mm");
```

if your `XMLdata.get("XMLField")` is `String` convert it into `float` do the above method.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView.setText((Math.floor(MathXMLdata.get("XMLField") * 100.0) / 100.0).toString() + " mm");`

This converts `10,5858555966668` to `1058,58555966668`, rounds it to `1058` and converts it back to `10,58`.

Note: `Math.floor` always rounds down (cuts off all missing fractional numbers). If you intend to round to the closest value, use `Math.round`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, thank you very much rmkrishna and Faro ((= I do it with

TextView.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(XMLData.get("Son7GunlukSagis").replace(",", ".")))+ " mm");